# Parsing the Freebase Topic HTTP API - JSON & Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, freebase, mql

I am trying to parse a JSON output:

http://www.freebase.com/experimental/topic/standard?id=/en/colonel_sanders

I'd like to put the basic data into an array using Javascript. In the "properties" object I'd like to grab any "text" element one level under "properties" as a label and grab the "text" under the "values" object to match the label.

For the above I would get:

- "description": "Harland David
  Sanders, better known as Colonel
  Sanders...
- "Organizations founded": KFC
- "Cause of death": Leukemia
- "Date of death": Dec 16, 1980
- "Place of
  death": Louisville
- "Date of birth":
  Sep 9, 1890
- "Gender": Male

etc...

I have some code which recursively runs through the JSON but I am a novice with javascript and JSON and am having a lot trouble in step one:

Firstly, grabbing the "text" trying by identifying an element as being "an element of" the main properties object; then

Secondly grabbing from the associated values array any text element (if the value is a collection then I would like to concatenate the strings from the text or otherwise ignore it).

I hope that make sense.

nb. the code I use is similar to here:
*http://tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
<script>
  function cb(response) {
    var props = {};
    var properties = response['/en/colonel_sanders'].result.properties;
    for (var p_id in properties) {
      var prop = properties[p_id];
      props[prop.text]=prop.values[0].text;
    }
    console.log(props);
  }
</script>
<script src="http://www.freebase.com/experimental/topic/standard?id=/en/colonel_sanders&callback=cb"></script>
```